# Remove connection object immediately after closing connection

Tags: r

This is a two-part question regarding the following chunk of code.

```
> ## ran rm(list = ls()) prior to the following
> closeAllConnections()
> tc <- textConnection("messages", "w")
> isOpen(tc)
# [1] TRUE
> close(tc)
> ls()
# [1] "messages" "tc" 
> is.object(tc)
# [1] TRUE     
> class(tc)
# [1] "textConnection" "connection"      
> tc
# Error in summary.connection(x) : invalid connection
```

1. Why isn't `tc` removed from the list of objects, `ls()`, immediately when the `tc` connection is closed, and what does `invalid connection` mean?  Is there a reason why R keeps `tc` in the list?
2. Is there a way to remove it from the object list immediately after it's closed?  I really don't want to call `rm()` if it's not necessary. Perhaps I missed an argument somewhere while scanning the help files.

The reason this is important is because I have a function called `list.objects` that returns an error after I run the above code, but does not otherwise (possibly because `tc` has two classes).

Comment: Opening a `textConnection` with a NULL object does not appear to have documented behavior on that function's help page. Are you expecting something in particular?

Comment: I wrote `NULL` just for this example.  But in my actual code, the connection has the name `"messages"`.  I'll edit.  The same behavior occurs for both though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1., tc isn't removed from the list of objects because `close` doesn't delete the variable you use to contain the pointer to the connection.  Rather, close closes the pointer and effectively removes it from the open file connections list (see `showConnections`).  The variable that contains the pointer still exists, it's just that the pointer points nowhere.  This explains why you get an error when you type `tc` after you close it, you're trying to look at a file connection that goes nowhere.

For 2., what's so hard about `close(tc); rm(tc)`?  Hardly any more typing than if there actually was a "delete my first argument" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`tc` is a variable that holds a reference to certain state. There is no particular reason that a call to `close()` should come with an `rm()` built-in. That would be like expecting a TV remote to disappear on its own after you turn off the TV by hitting the power button.

I think you will have to call `rm(tc)` to remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I guess `rm(tc)` is probably one of the shortest of all my executions anyhow, byte-wise.

Comment: @jbaums, Thank you. I think analogies in the real world help us escape the world of bits and bytes just a little bit. :)